# Ring Theory - Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need some help with starting this problem. I am given that $$C=\left\{\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{array} \right): a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$ is a subring of the ring of all $2\times2$ matrices with real number entries, with respect to usual addition and multiplation of matrices. My task is to show that $C$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $f(\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{array} \right)) = a + ib$ looks like a natural candidate

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

we have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
-b&a
\end{bmatrix}=
a
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
+b
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow 1
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow i
$$